# What is the difference between web sockets, long polling, server-sent events and forever frame?

Tags: websocket, signalr, long-polling, server-sent-events

I'm currently exploring SignalR, this technology supports transports (web wockets, long polling ,server-sent events and forever frame).

I have understood the terminology web sockets and long polling. But what is Server-Sent Events and Forever Frame?

How all four differ from each other?

Comment: Information on all the transport types can be found in the Introduction to SignalR document at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Answer (score 25):

**Transports and fallbacks of SignalR:**

**WebSocket** `Full-duplex`

Websocket is a full-duplex communication channels over a single TCP connection. When both server and browser support, it is the **only transport that establishes a true persistent, two-way connection** between client and server.

**Server Sent Events** `Simplex`

also known as EventSource is a technology where a **browser receives automatic updates from a server** via HTTP connection. The Server-Sent Events EventSource API is standardized as part of HTML5 by the W3C.

**Forever Frame** `One request -> One infinite response`

Forever Frame creates a **hidden IFrame** which makes a request to an endpoint on the server **that does not complete**. The server then continually sends script to the client which is immediately executed, providing a one-way realtime connection from server to client. The connection from client to server uses a separate connection from the server to client connection, and like a standard HTTP request, a new connection is created for each piece of data that needs to be sent.

**Ajax long polling** `(One Request -> One Response [but delayed]) repeated`

Long polling does not create a persistent connection, but instead polls the server with a **request that stays open until the server responds**, at which point the connection closes, and a new connection is requested immediately. This may introduce some latency while the connection resets.

*More info:*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events