# How to update Php web page when db data changes from another device with android app?

Tags: php, android, database, triggers

Which is the correct way to do this: I have a pc with a php web application (as admin user) to "control" data (for example notes) but the notes are inserted in the db through a web service(APiRest) from android devices(using a simple app) which other users inserts in real time, but these notes must be checked by the admin in the pc(with a boolean value, e.g. "checked" or not). So, how to automatically update the admin web page when a user from the android app inserts a new note? Should I use triggers? What is the correct technique? Any suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), [Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) or a [Forever Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571581/what-is-the-difference-between-forever-frame-and-server-sent-events), if you want the admin to update automatically. Or you can use a server send event from the back-end towards the browser.

Comment: which one you recommend to a begginer  Websockets, Polling or a Forever Frame? .
server send event? you mean server to the db server? or the api or my php web application(I'm using Laravel)? from where should i send the event? could you explain it with more details please? thanks in advance

Comment: @matQ the very best is to use WebSockets, which will provide a duplex connection. However, some servers do not support such a modern protocol. The second best is Server send event, or, in other words, push notifications, which is a way to send a message from the server to the target audience, in this case the browser of the admin. The third best is polling. Forever frame is still a solution, but not as good as the other three.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column to your table (for example `approved`), and set its default value to `0`. When the user adds a note from the app (adds a row to the table), the `approved` column will be set to `0`. In the PHP admin panel, you can modify the select query like so:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE approved=0`

With this, only the rows that have not been approved will be shown, allowing the admin to approve them.

Comment: And how will this idea update the admin panel real-time exactly when the change occurred?

Comment: yes @LajosArpad is right i need that the inserted row update the admin page in real time automatically